# Why aren't elements of a fieldset by extension associated with the form the fieldset is associated with?

Tags: html

Is there any "good" reason that with HTML 5 and its novel `form` attribute for form elements, elements that are themselves descendants of a `fieldset` element, are *not* associated with the same form the fieldset is associated with?

It does not make sense to me, as the fieldset contains these elements, why would it contain elements associated with another form or not associated with any form at all.

Consider the following example:

```
<form id="myform"></form>
<fieldset form="foobar">
    <input name="myinput"></input>
</fieldset>
```

Evaluating the `form` property of the input element yields `null`. My common sense tells me that a descendant of a fieldset that is associated with a form, should also be associated with the same form, by default.

Am I missing some logic that a standards committee didn't miss? Or is this just legacy and backwards compatibility case?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it looks like you have to do a recursive lookup, see the snippet.

Maybe the reason is because now you can detect if an element has specified a form by itself or not, but that is just a guess.

By the way I noticed that your example is slightly wrong: you need to use **`<form id="....">`**.

```js
console.log('myfieldset -> ' + findForm(document.getElementById('myfieldset')));
console.log('myinput    -> ' + findForm(document.getElementById('myinput')));
console.log('myinput2   -> ' + findForm(document.getElementById('myinput2')));

function findForm(el) {
  if (el.form) return el.form.id;
  if (el.parentNode) return findForm(el.parentNode);
  return null;
}
```

```html
<form id="myform"></form>
<form id="myform2"></form>

<fieldset id="myfieldset" form="myform">
  <input id="myinput" name="myinput" />
  <input id="myinput2" name="myinput2" form="myform2" />
</fieldset>
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out my omission with `name` vs `id` attribute being used. I have edited my question. That said, yes, one could do the kind of lookup you suggest. I just instead figure out and assign the `form` attribute on such elements automatically, with a script. Still, I think the whole story is a bit strange. Just as the story with `fieldset` elements which are always valid. I think the whole business with HTML forms needs some standards committee attention, but that's a digression.